# How to get specific extrinsic using python substrate interface

Tags: substrateinterface

I am using python substrate Interface (https://github.com/polkascan/py-substrate-interface) to interact with the substrate node.

I need to execute Pallet::Balances::transfer twice by combine both of my transaction in the  utility batch. Now I wanted to retrieve the status and other details of my transaction. How  Can I do that. Following is the code that I am using:

```python
from substrateinterface import SubstrateInterface, Keypair
from tools.utils import show_extrinsic, WS_URL, TOKEN_NUM_BASE,transfer
from tools.two_address_substrate_with_extrinsic import show_account 
  
def pallet_utility_test():
    substrate = SubstrateInterface (
        url=WS_URL
)

    kp_src = Keypair.create_from_uri('//Alice')
    kp_dst=Keypair.create_from_uri('//Bob')
  

 
   
    nonce = substrate.get_account_nonce(kp_src.ss58_address)
    amount_to_be_transfered= 10  
    
    #first valid transaciton
    payload_first = substrate.compose_call(
        call_module='Balances',
        call_function='transfer',
        call_params={
            'dest': kp_dst.ss58_address,
            'value': amount_to_be_transfered * TOKEN_NUM_BASE
        })

    #Second invalid transaciton
    payload_second = substrate.compose_call(
        call_module='Balances',
        call_function='force_transfer',
        call_params={
            'source': kp_src.ss58_address, 
            'dest': kp_dst.ss58_address,
            'value': amount_to_be_transfered * TOKEN_NUM_BASE
        })


    batch = substrate.compose_call(
        call_module='Utility',
        call_function='batch',
        call_params={
            'calls': [payload_first.value, payload_second.value],
        })

    extrinsic = substrate.create_signed_extrinsic(
        call=batch,
        keypair= kp_src,
        era={'period': 64},
        nonce=nonce
    )

    receipt = substrate.submit_extrinsic(extrinsic, wait_for_inclusion=True)
    
    if not receipt.is_success:
        print(substrate.get_events(receipt.block_hash))
        raise IOError
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wait for the extrinsic to be finalized by setting `wait_for_finalization=True` in the `submit_extrinsic` call, you will get back relevant information in the receipt. The best resource for this is the [docs](https://github.com/polkascan/py-substrate-interface#examining-the-extrinsicreceipt-object) or in the [extrinsic receipt source code](https://github.com/polkascan/py-substrate-interface/blob/master/substrateinterface/base.py#L3312).

For instance, you can look at

- `receipt.triggered_events` to get the events that were triggered by the transaction
- `receipt.is_success` like you already do to see if it succeeded
- `receipt.extrinsic` to get info about the extrinsic itself
- `receipt.error_message` to get info about how it failed, if it failed